# Widget UI not updating in response to broadcast

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a couple of widgets which are basically quick links to functionality within my app,

These widgets are basically ListView/GridViews which are being backed by data that changes during the main App's execution.

Since the data is only changed during app execution the update frequency is set as so:

```
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
```

and on the data changed I fire the following:

```
public void updateWidget(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class provider) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
    int[] gridids = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(this.getPackageName(), provider.getName()));

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, provider);
    intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,gridids);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

I'm able to catch this in the `onReceive()` of the Provider and from their call the update mechanism:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onReceive()");
    int[] ids = intent.getExtras().getIntArray("appWidgetIds");
    for(int id : ids) onUpdateWithService(context, id);
}

protected void onUpdateWithService(Context context, int widgetId) {     
    super.onUpdateWithService(context, widgetId);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), getResourceLayout(context, widgetId));                    

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridViewWidgetServiceAdapter.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listView, intent);
    views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listView, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, -1, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
}
```

The problem I'm having is that although the code fires and `updateAppWidget()` is called, the UI of the widget doesn't change.

Am I missing a trick involved in Widget updates?

Comment: Also keep in mind that, setting android:updatePeriodMillis below 30 minute will not set it to that time, it will fallback automatically to 30 minute. 30 minute minimum timer can be overridden only using code.

Comment: @Milanix - Not according to the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) - Setting it to 0 disables the automatic updating.

Comment: Ahh missed that, thank you. Can't stop learning :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13203924/726954) seems to fix the problem.

Not sure *why* it fixes the problem, but it does...

Adding the following line to the intent works fine

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, GridViewWidgetServiceAdapter.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
intent.putExtra("Random", Math.random() * 1000); // Add a random integer to stop the Intent being ignored.
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
```

Comment: About "Not sure why it fixes the problem, but it does...": Android seems to be caching the intents you use in your onUpdate method. Also Remoteviews are cached by default. So you need to send the different number each time. Its similar to concept of jquery caching where you fetch jquery as "./jquery.js?v=somerandomnumebr" to avoid caching.

Comment: Its ridicolous but this really fixes the problem