# Android widget disable listitem nested button onclick

Tags: android, android-widget

I am making an android app which is having a listview with clickable buttons(nested listview). The Homescreen widget of the app is also having almost same layout.

There is need to disable button after click. In the activity, I can easily disable button as:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Disable Button
                    v.setEnabled(false);

                    // Mark item as not received
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

For the widget part, I am using [RemoteViewFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html) to setup the listitems with buttons. Code follows:

```
public class ListProvider implements RemoteViewsFactory {
.....

   public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
      final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row); //The layout of single list row
     remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, "Some Heading");
     remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, "Some Content");
     Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
     fillInIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
     remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.buttonwidget, fillInIntent);
     .....
   }
.....
}
```

Now that the intent on the button has been setup, I can receive it in the WidgetProvider's `onReceive()` method as:

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
   public static final String EXTRA_ITEM = "com.example.android.stackwidget.EXTRA_ITEM";
   public static final String ACTION_START_ACTIVITY = "startActivity";

@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,appWidgetIds[i]);
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
            clickIntent.setAction(ACTION_START_ACTIVITY);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, clickIntent, 0);
            remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, pendingIntent);

        }

        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
   }

   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int appWidgetId = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,appWidgetId);
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        //Printing detail of clicked item from widget
        if(ACTION_START_ACTIVITY.equals(intent.getAction())) {
             //Disable the button
             remoteViews.setBoolean(R.id.buttonwidget, "setEnabled", false);
             Toast.makeText(context, "Widget Button Clicked",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //Update the widget again
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
   }
}
```

This method is also working good except that it updates only the button of first listitem. I want to disable the button of corresponding listitem that is being clicked. So I might be needing a position element. So I thought of getting the intent in RemoteViewsFactory's `getViewAt` method as it holds the position of listitem. But I am not able to get the intent. Here is the modified code of `RemoteViewsFactory`:

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
          final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row); //The layout of single list row
         remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.heading, "Some Heading");
         remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.content, "Some Content");

         //Get the intent of button here
         if(WidgetProvider.ACTION_START_ACTIVITY.equals(this.remoteIntent.getAction())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Listitem Complete Button Clicked: "+position,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

         Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
         fillInIntent.putExtra(WidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
         remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.buttonwidget, fillInIntent);
         .....
       }
```

So I hope you guys got the point. How do I set/change the button at some specific position of itemitem?

**EDIT:** I applied the solution given below and it got me working. I can now reveive the intents and the corresponding data along with it. I still had one problem left. The button needs to be change to some other image, depending upon the state. In simple sense, the listview needed to be updated, which I did by generating the random number and sending it along with service intent.
As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183415/widget-ui-not-updating-in-response-to-broadcast).

Comment: What does mean (nested listview)? Do you mean expandable listview?

Comment: A simple listview that is having two buttons inside it. That is what I meant. Normal listview will have a heading and content. Mine is having two buttons besides it.

Comment: Buddy its simply a custom listview

Comment: I was reading a book on android and following many tutorials where I have came across **nested listview** consisting of buttons and simple text so i thought. Anyways, can you still give some light on solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way I have implemented something similar:

In the class that implements `RemoteViewsFactory`, I have an ArrayList of custom objects. I use these to inflate and return `RemoteViews` from the `getViewAt(int)` method. One of the members of my custom object is `boolean isEnabled`. Based on user choice, I set this member variable and call refresh/update on my widget.

Inside the `getViewAt(int)` method, I check the value of `isEnabled` and act on it:

```
@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    final RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(
    mContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget_listview);

    MyCustomObj info = mEntries.get(position);

    if (info.isEnabled()) {
        remoteView.setBoolean(R.id.buttonwidget, "setEnabled", true);
    } else {
        remoteView.setBoolean(R.id.buttonwidget, "setEnabled", false);
    }

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(Constants.POSITION_IN_LIST, position);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    remoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.buttonwidget, fillInIntent);

    return remoteView;
}
```

Inside `onReceive(Context, Intent)`, I get the position of the clicked button - and update the `isEnabled` status of `MyCustomObj` at that position - and update the widget.

Comment: I used your code and the error I got is: `The method isEnabled() is undefined for the type ListItem` where `ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);`. The `listItemList` is the `ArrayList` variable

Comment: @ashutosh Can you post the code for class representing `ListItem`?

Comment: `ListItem` is defined in the LsitProvider class which extends `RemoteViewFactory`. The whole class is [here](http://pastebin.com/ufeLgv7L)

Comment: @ashutosh From looking at the code you posted, `ListItem` is not defined inside `ListProvider`. I want to see the actual code for `ListItem` such as: `public class ListItem { .... .... }`.

Comment: `ListItem` is not a class. Looking at the code, you can see the `listItemList` as new `ArrayList` is initialized and further populated with the items of list(fetched from database) in `populateListItem()` method. In `getViewAt(int position)` method, you can see the code: `ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);` . So it is the instance/item retrieved at certain position from ArrayList

Comment: @ashutosh I think you are getting confused. When you say `ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);`, `listItem` is the instance. But, `ListItem` is the class/interface. `ArrayLists` store objects. Objects have definitions. I want to see `ListItem's` definition. Because that's where `isEnabled()` will have to be added for this to work.

Comment: I used your code lately and its working quite fine. Only problem now is, the app widget does not get updated. What would you suggest to update it?

Comment: @ashutosh If you only want the ListView content to refresh, use `mAppWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetID, R.id.listview_id);`. This will invoke the adapter, which I assume has access to fresh data.